# Getting `Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code` error

Tags: swift, swiftui

Error 1: Unable to run the swiftUI project.

Error2: Command EmitSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
Check Automatically manage signing and choose right Team in Xcode

[image]

Comment: Yes, `Automatically manage signing` and `Team` is properly selected.

Comment: hm usually it should work then.

You can try this things: clean build, reboot PC/Laptop, check again if your iPhone is selected for run, go to Settings in your iPhone and allow permission to simulate.

Comment: It is running in iPhone but not running in simulator. What could cause this?

Comment: For example sometimes it happened to me, when I used Proxyman (such a http manipulation application). Or you have to choose right target (next to Select Simulator field). But if it doesn't work, let's wait for other people's solutions!